# C#, Get other application text from TextBox and TextArea?

Tags: c#, textbox, hook

Good morgning,

I would like to be able to analyze text where I am writting whatever the application I am. Example, If I am here, typing in this TextArea, I would like to be able to get the text, same way if I were in the Subject Textbox in my Outlook.

I have search Google without success, maybe it's because it require Win32API call.

The goal would be to start having fun with multiple algorithm like "Bloom Filter" and Markov Chain.

Is it possible with C# and how to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodingTheWheels series on building a poker bot goes into detail on how to capture window events from other applications. Its not exactly what your looking for, but it has some good info.

http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/how-i-built-a-working-poker-bot

Answer (score 1):

This tool works perfectly fine even for non-managed processess.

[Runtime Object Editor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/RuntimeObjectEditor.aspx)