# Using textbox defined in one project to another project

Tags: c#

Is there anyway to access the textboxes defined in one project to the other project using c#

Thanks for suggestion

Comment: What do you mean my accessing textbox of another project? Are you talking of accessing textbox of another application or do you mean to say you want to add a textbox defined in another project? Can you me more specific ?

Comment: yes I want to add textbox defined in another project

Comment: You have a subclassed, custom textbox control defined in one project, and you want to be able to use that textbox control in a different project? Are these projects together in a single solution? Or are they part of separate apps?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do that with native win32 api calls.

See this question:
[C#, Get other application text from TextBox and TextArea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162154/c-get-other-application-text-from-textbox-and-textarea)