# Reading Excel's Edit box

Tags: .net, excel, winapi

After some digging, it turns out that Excel's edit control is not standard Windows TextBox and I'm seemingly unable to do `GetWindowText()` on it. Doing a Spy on it reveals it belongs to a class named `EXCEL6`. Is there a way to get text from non-standard text controls using platform calls or something?

Later I found in MSDN that GetWindowText() doesn't work with controls belonging to other processes and that I need to send WM_GETTEXT directly to the target window. I tried that too, but it seemingly returns garbage data.

Comment: This may be helpful to you - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14292/Runtime-Object-Editor

Comment: mmm... The author seems to be telling in the very first line that this is for managed apps. A few questions at the bottom also ask how to use this for unmanaged apps. I'd highly doubt that Excel's been written in a managed app. Thoughts?

Comment: Aah, I was basing my comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/162242/969613) which suggested it works with non-manages apps.

Comment: I just gave it a try and it seemingly cannot read anything other than the class name: `EXCEL6`.

Comment: Ah no problem, hopefully somebody can be more helpful!

Comment: Excel exposes an [object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that you can work with directly rather than fiddling with low-level window primitives.

Comment: @Luke: The Excel object model doesn't expose anything to grab the contents of Excel's Edit box. It does have a Worksheet_Change event, but by the time that is raised, the original contents of the edit box have long been vanished into the thin air and what I get is only the converted version of the original input. Try entering **1E9** in a cell and see what the object model returns in the Change event.

Comment: @dotNET: I just tested this using your example.  In the SheetChange event I see Range.Text = "1.00E+09" (string) and Range.Value = "1000000000.0" (double).  I'm not sure why you would need "1E9" when you have the actual value.

Comment: The point is that in my case 1E9 is the ACTUAL value, non-numeric, non-scientific, pure text. It could be 3B6 or 9M7 too. While these other examples don't get converted, 1E9 and any other mEn gets converted into scientific value, which is what I don't want. One work-around is to pre-apply Text formatting, but since my user could input these values in almost any cell in the entire worksheet, I'm reluctant to go for that option, as it would disable Excel's standard numeric operations too.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but how do you know if the user actually means "1E9" or "1,000,000"?  If you know beforehand you can change the cell formatting.  If you don't know beforehand then there's not much you can do since the information is lost during the format conversion; it will be up to the user to notice and correct it.  The edit control being used is a private class so there's no telling how to get the text out of it.

Comment: Agreed, but my user will never need to enter IE9 for scientific notation, and yet I cannot afford to pre-apply Text formatting on the entire sheet for the reason I mentioned above. Also note that 1E9 and 10E8 produce the same numeric value, so I don't even have the option to apply text formatting on-the-fly.